# libssl.so.1.1 is installed but Anchor doesn't detect it on Fedora Linux

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, build-bpf

[image]

I tried installing `libssl.so.1.1` using `sudo dnf install libssl.so.1.1`, and I can clearly see it is installed (as shown in the screenshow above). However Anchor is still not able to detect it. Most of the answers regarding this same issue are for Debian based distros and those solutions work for them, but unable to figure it out here in this case for my Fedora system.

Further, I also tried setting the variable `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1`, which didn'
t work either.

Comment: I'm surprised that it's still looking for such an old version of the library -- is there a chance that one of your tools is out of date? See if you can update to the newest anchor (0.29 as of now) and supported Solana version (which appears to be 1.17)

Comment: Yes they are. I figured out that using `sudo yum install openssl1.1` solved it. Unsure exactly how though.